# Bevel sharp edges in circular shape

Tags: bevel

I'm working in blender and I'm trying to bevel a 45° edge into a circular shaped corner.

The problem is that the bevel follows a sharper trajectory (not a circle shape, but more like an oval).

I tried it with the superellipse and the support loops profile types, but both don't give me the shape I want. By changing the shape value I can approximately get the shape I want, but I want it to be **exact**.

**My question is:** Is there any way to bevel the 45° edge to be exactly circular shaped?

I already applied the scale, so that's not the problem.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Edit: I added a screenshot. The orange line is the current curve and the red circle shows the path I want the bevel to follow.

I also tried making a custom profile type, but this also didn't have the outcome I wanted (I have to admit I'm not an expert in making custom profiles, so maybe someone can help me with this)

Comment: Can you show sreenshots?

Comment: Added a screenshot

Comment: Have you tried using a custom profile (option pictured at bottom of your screenshot)?

Comment: I just tried this. I drew a circular shape (manually, so it wasn't an exact circle, but close enough) and applied it. I get about the same result as with the superellipse profile.

Comment: Encountered this while trying to find a way to create outline edges equal distance to each edges in mesh, kinda sad this won't work that easily

Answer (score 2):

Seems to me like .375 in the shape parameter is about as close as it gets.

I rationalized this from the knowledge that .5 == perfectly round within a 90 degree corner and .25 == a straight between the bevel points.

45 degrees is halfway between 90 and 0, therefore i just entered `(.5 + .25) / 2` into the parameter and hey, It kinda seems like that's it.

[image]

With a mesh circle next to it for comparison:

[image]

If that's not good enough then by all means, feel free to sift through the 7600+ lines of C++ code in the BMesh bevel operator and maybe read a refresher on calculus and graphing superellipses while you're at it lmao. It's not super simple what goes on under the hood.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Seems logical and the outcome is very close. I'm sure it's a complex matter. Was definitely not trying to discredit the bevel function in any way.

Comment: Yeah, lol I only mention it cause I was curious and tried to dive into the code to see if I could make sense of it and uh... no..I could not.

Comment: Aha okay, well thanks again since your help got me the closest thus far.